# Django initial data for built-in app

Tags: django, django-orm, django-migrations, django-contrib

I'm starting to use the "redirects" app built into Django to replace some existing redirects I have in my `urls.py`.  I was wondering if there was any generally accepted way to include initial data in the code base for other apps.  For example, if it was for an app I created I could create a migration file that had a `RunPython` section where I could load some initial data.  With a built-in or third-party app there doesn't seem to be any way to create a migration file to add initial data.

The best I can think of right now is to include a .sql file in my repository with the initial data and just manually import the data as I push the code to the different instances.

Answer (score 2):

you can do it by using  fixtures

create a folder name `fixtures` in your app directory

use this command to create a json file that you want to make as initial data.

```
 python manage.py dumpdata you_app_name.model_name --indent 2 > model_name.json
```

copy this `model_name.json` to `fixtures` folder.

upload the code to the repo.

then after the  `migrate command` . Type this command to load the initial data.

```
  python manage.py loaddata model_name.json
```

[reference](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/howto/initial-data/)

Comment: I see that I can create a project-wide fixtures directory with `FIXTURE_DIRS` so I guess this is the best option so far.  However, it still requires a manual action after the migration.

Comment: @TimTisdall if you are using linux os. then you can write a aliases command and pass python manage.py migrate && python manage.py loaddata. so it will do to both in a single step. or use python fab (Fabric) and write a function to do all commands in a single call.

Comment: @TimTisdall . i think its the solution. i dont know more.

Comment: I agree, I don't think there's a better solution than this, but it requires knowing to run the `loaddata` in the same way that a person would need to know to run an independent .sql file.  I was hoping for a way to link into the migration system.